# k6 environmental variables results in GO error "invalid character"

Tags: k6

k6 docs make using environmental variables very simple and I tried following their instructions, but I get a GO error when I try to run it:

`ERRO[0000] GoError: parse  https://${__ENV.TARGET_ENV}-api.mycompany.com/v1/managers/259999/properties": invalid character "{" in host name".`

I don't see an extra bracket anywhere. This script was working fine when I had the url as https://green-api.mycompany.com/v1/managers/259999/properties. Am I possibly missing an import or dependency somewhere? All I am trying to do is get it working to where when i type k6 run --env TARGET_ENV=green propertiesScript.js, it executes against http://green-api.mycompany.com/v1/managers/259999/properties. Here is the file:

```
import { check } from "k6";

export let options = {
  thresholds: {
    http_req_duration: ["p(90)<300"], // 95% of requests should be below 200ms
    Errors: ["count<100"],
  },
};

export default function () {
  var url =
    "https://${__ENV.TARGET_ENV}-api.mycompany.com/v1/managers/259999/properties";

  const params = {
    headers: {
      "X-App-Token": "<our app token>",
      "X-Auth-Token":
        "<our auth token>",
      accept: "application/json",
    },
  };

  let res = http.get(url, params);
  console.log(res.body);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers));

  check(res, {
    "status is 200": (r) => r.status === 200,
  });
}
```

I also tried adding scenarios and adjusting the body of my file. These are the scenarios:

```
  thresholds: {
    http_req_duration: ["p(90)<300"], // 95% of requests should be below 200ms
    Errors: ["count<100"],
  },
  scenarios: {
    pod_green: {
      tags: { my_custom_tag: "green" },
      env: { MYVAR: "green" },
      executor: "shared-iterations",
    },
    pod_red: {
      tags: { my_custom_tag: "red" },
      env: { MYVAR: "red" },
      executor: "shared-iterations",
    },
    staging: {
      tags: { my_custom_tag: "staging" },
      env: { MYVAR: "staging" },
      executor: "shared-iterations",
    },
  },
};
```

Then I edited my export default function and I was able to get that script to run, but it runs against every single environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backticks when you set the `url` variable for string interpolation to work in template literals. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

So in your case you should have:

```js
var url =
    `https://${__ENV.TARGET_ENV}-api.mycompany.com/v1/managers/259999/properties`;
```